# Correct way to address top UITabBarController view for showFromTabBar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiactionsheet

Main app delegate has a UITabBarController called tabBarController (NewsUKDelegate.m)

The first tab loads a UIViewController which turns adds a UITableView (FirstViewController.m)

The UITableView loads a subclass UIViewController when a cell is selected (StoryController.m)

I'm then loading the share actionsheet from Sharekit

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:storyTitle];
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:rootView];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:[self view]];
```

It works(ish) but the actionsheet loads from the top which seems wrong, but importantly it complains of

```
incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIView *', expected 'struct UITabBar *' 
when passing argument 1 of 'showFromTabBar:' from distinct Objective-C type
```

I've tried fooling around with

```
UIWindow *topWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

if (topWindow.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal)
{
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for(topWindow in windows)
    {
        if (topWindow.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal)
            break;
    }
}

UIView *rootView = [[topWindow subviews] objectAtIndex:0];  
NSLog(@"Root view is: %@",rootView);

[actionSheet showFromTabBar:rootView];
    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:NewsUKDelegate.tabBarController];
    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:NewsUKDelegate.view];
```

But I just get crashes, what's the correct way to address the main app's delegate toolbar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use,

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Comment: I get crashes on this line! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
     ((myAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).delegate.tabBar
```

Comment: Using karim's solution as I have to import the App delegate header anyway so tabBarController is already defined, but yours looks good for more general use, thank you.

Comment: @JulianB - Karim's solution uses less punctuation than mine, so is better by definition :-)